# php - preg_replace is duplicating the tags and not replacing them

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, src

Trying to look inside my imap messages and if any img tags are found replace them with a new link.

have at look here:
http://codepad.viper-7.com/WGxtw7

So far I have

```
$message = imap_fetchbody($imap,$email_number,"2"); //2
$message = quoted_printable_decode($message);

$img_replace = $message;
$img_replace = preg_replace('~src="cid.*?"~',"src=\"new-link\"", $img_replace);
echo $img_replace;
```

With this code I get the img tags with the new links however, instead of being replaced they are duplicate so  my final  output is showing both links and imgs.

the generated message will show something like the html below, the src, width and height are always different and just the src needs to be replaced(no duplicated) with a new link.

```
    <h2>Message: <div dir="ltr">this is a test with 2 inline images<div><br></div>
<div><img src="cid:ii_iaa9ibac0_14da215402096e51" width="544" height="340"><br><br></div>
<div><br></div><div><img src="cid:ii_iaa9inn31_14da2157f7bb06e9" width="405" height="405"><br><br></div></div>
    </h2>
```

It should look like:

```
    <h2>Message: <div dir="ltr">this is a test with 2 inline images<div><br></div>
<div><img src="new-link" width="544" height="340"><br><br></div>
<div><br></div><div><img src="new-link" width="405" height="405"><br><br></div></div>
    </h2>
```

So what I was thinking is to get a function that will:

- Look inside the final html
- if img src attributes start with 'cid:'
- replace the src link with 'new-link'

Any Idea?

Comment: i've tried. code is fine

Comment: I know it works but it duplicates the html and not replacing it. http://codepad.viper-7.com/WGxtw7

Comment: There you echo twice

Comment: comment the first echo and show text not html http://codepad.viper-7.com/qFHLoT

Comment: it works thanks … I was echoing both of them

Comment: Are you going to accept the answer from yesterday since it appears you are using it here? Also as stated yesterday, the code works fine, you aren't passing in the data you are saying you are.

Comment: sorry Chris yes accepted sorry was deeming in the code